# MySQL (Aurora) update timestamp using adddate or date-add or date-sub says syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, date-arithmetic, aws-aurora-serverless

Can any of you figure out what is the syntax error on mySQL update statement here ?

`update table_name set start_time = DATE_ADD (start_time , INTERVAL 2 DAY) where start_time = '2020-12-08 10:47:00';`

The above is simple mySQL query to update start_time (time stamp) by 2 days.

AFAIK, the above should work and its nothing complicated. But i am getting syntax error and i am not able to comprehend why there is a syntax error.  Here is the error i got...

> Database error code: 1064. Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') where start_time = '2020-12-08 10:47:00'' at line 10

I have also tried other variants such as...

```
update table_name set start_time = adddate (start_time , INTERVAL 2 DAY) where start_time = '2020-12-08 10:47:00';

update table_name set start_time = date_sub (start_time , INTERVAL -2 DAY) where start_time = '2020-12-08 10:47:00';
```

> Database error code: 1064. Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') where start_time = '2020-12-08 10:47:00'' at line 3

If i use the date_sub in select statement,

```
select * from table_name where start_time  > DATE_SUB(now() , INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

it does work like a charm. But i am not able to use it in update statement for set =....

I am just not able to comprehend what is going wrong and curious to know what is wrong with the syntax. Can you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is the space between the function name and the opening parenthese.

This:

```
DATE_ADD (start_time , INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Should be written:

```
DATE_ADD(start_time , INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

This is not happening in the example using `DATE_SUB()`, because the leading space is not there.

Not all MySQL functions have such restriction. This is related to the way the MySQL parser handles function names, which is [described in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/function-resolution.html):

> The requirement that function calls be written with no whitespace between the name and the parenthesis applies only to the built-in functions that have special considerations.

`DATE_ADD()` and `DATE_SUB()` are listed as affected functions. You can play around with [SQL mode `IGNORE_SPACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) to change the default behavior.

Overall, I would recommend using date arithmetic like so, so you don't need to worry about such caveat (and it makes for more readable code as well):

```
start_time + INTERVAL 2 day
```

Comment: I honestly dont know what to say. That was my first post here and i hardly expected anyone to answer. @GMB Your profile shows lot of SQL/DB.  I like DBMS & SQL and was so curious why it was not working - it seems to be a mild 'bug' to me. Should this be reported as a bug?

Comment: @Arun: welcome. I digged in the documentation: this is not a bug. I edited my answer with more information.